# Customize the reset password page?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

How can I style the reset password page, where I put in my new password?

I tried going like this:

```
function my_login_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
        'custom-login', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/styles/main.css' 
    );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_stylesheet' );
```

but it added the CSS only to the login and forgot password page (forgot password as in the page where you put in your email).

However, I want to style the reset password page (where you put in your passwords).

Comment: That's strange, it is the same page, calling same hooks essentially. Had you verified that your file isn't loading at all? It might be just that your CSS rules are off.

Comment: @Rarst yes i'm sure. try it out yourself.

Comment: @AryehArmon - Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce overrides default account management templates with its own shortcode driven templating system. Use this hook instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_lostpassword_form', 'do_whatever');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i am not using woocommerce, not sure why you think i am.

Comment: Then a theme or a plugin is overriding the default Wordpress account management. Look for it. If you want an simple diagnostic, then simply run your code on a fresh Wordpress install.

Comment: it is a fresh wordpress install.